# Switching back : pypy =to=> python?

Tags: python, pypy, libs

I installed pypy to test it !
Now when I try to do something it seems to prefer pypy directories , instead of python. Ex.:

```
 # pip install --upgrade setuptools
 /usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util............


#  ls /usr/local/lib/p
perl/      pypy2.7/   python2.7/ python3.4/
```

Is there way to revert to use python libs ?
I'm OK with leaving pypy installed for future tests.

Comment: There are two possible issues here. (1) `echo $PATH`. Does something to do with `pypy` come before something to do with `python2.7` and even `/usr/local/bin`? Then that's what you need to fix. Which is probably a matter of your shell's profile files, which you can probably get better help for on a site like SuperUser than here.

Comment: (2) `which pip` and then `ls -l $(which pip)` and `less $(which pip)`. If you find that `/usr/local/bin/pip` is a symlink to something in pypy, or it has a pypy `#!` line, then your separate Pythons all installed `pip` over each other, and whoever came last won. You can work around this by writing `python -m pip` and `pypy -m pip` and so on, but the only way to actually solve it is to manually set up symlinks with different names (e.g., I have `pip3`, `pip2`, `pippy3`, and `pippy2` in my path).

Comment: Alternative, you could just use virtualenvs and avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can cause this behavior.  My first suggestion would be to uninstall PyPy.  If you don't want to uninstall PyPy, I suggest the following:

1. Check your system path variable.  If PyPy is found earlier than Python, that's what will be executed.  Remove the path to the PyPy or move the path to PyPy AFTER the path for Python.
2. Check for symlinks to pip found in PyPy and point them to pip from Python.

Tip: Use virtual environments so you can have multiple versions of Python and modules installed on the same development platform without interfering with one another and avoid this problem entirely.